# Find in All subkey of Object MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this Document in mongodb

```
 {
    "name": "test2",
    "_id": "1502609098801598ffeca615f5d3dd09087c6",
    "events": {
        "0": {
            "delay": "0",
            "actionid": "2"
        },
        "1": {
            "delay": "0",
            "actionid": "3"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find documents that contain event with specific actionid
i tried something like these but i can't find what i want

```
db.mycollection.find({ "events.$.actionid":"2" })
db.mycollection.find({ "events.$**.actionid":"2" })
db.mycollection.find({ "events.$": { $elemMatch: { "actionid":"2"} })
```

attention please: i can't change document structure and mongodb version is  3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

We can take use of the aggregation feature within mongodb and [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the [object to an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)

```
db.test.aggregate( [ { "$project" : { "events" : { "$objectToArray" : "$events" } } } ] )
```

after this we can just use the normal array filtering with a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project":
        { "events": {"$objectToArray": "$events"} } },
    { "$match": 
        { "events.v.actionid" : "2" } } ] )
```

This will output the following:

```
{
        "_id" : "1502609098801598ffeca615f5d3dd09087c6",
        "events" : [
                {
                        "k" : "0",
                        "v" : {
                                "delay" : "0",
                                "actionid" : "2"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "k" : "1",
                        "v" : {
                                "delay" : "0",
                                "actionid" : "3"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
>
```

So you might want to project the document back to its orignial structure

Comment: i see this error
"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$objectToArray'"

Comment: What version of mongodb are you running? you'll need >= 3.4.4

Comment: i have  mongodb  3.0.6